# how can i bring "selected" paramter from dropdown in view page to implement a submit db save button function in controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net core to change statuses for some cases, I decided to edit the statuses field from the index page by dropdown list with a saving button near every row.

```
View:

               @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.StatusSTID, ViewBag.StatusList as 
               Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList, "--Select",{})
               <button>Save </button>

Controler: 

               List<Status> StatusList= _context.Status.ToList();
               ViewBag.StatusList = new SelectList(StatusList, "STID", "Name");
```

what is the paramter that i should use in button function(in the controler) to save the selected edited field to the db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample about how to edit the status field and save the edited value to database:

1.Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StatusSTID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int STID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestModel>
<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-action="Save" asp-route-id="@item.Id" method="post">
                    <select asp-for="@item.StatusSTID" asp-items="ViewBag.StatusList" name="Status"></select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </form>

            </td>                  
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3.Controller:

```
public class TestModelsController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public TestModelsController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: TestModels
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Status> StatusList = _context.Status.ToList();
        ViewBag.StatusList = new SelectList(StatusList, "STID", "Name");
        var data = _context.TestModel.Include(t => t.Status);
        return View(await data.ToListAsync());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save(int id,int Status)
    {
        var testModel =await _context.TestModel.FindAsync(id);
        testModel.StatusSTID = Status;
        _context.Update(testModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

4.Result:
[image]